# How to change the value of a column in export csv format in ui grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using UI grid export functionality to export all grid columns in .csv format.
Some columns values are 'FALSE' or '1' / '0' .
My question is How can I change them to some strings in exported file?

Comment: Take a look at [ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions), more specific, the `exporterFieldCallback` method. I think that is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions 
you can use exporterFieldCallBack method as below:

```
  gridOptions.exporterFieldCallback = function ( grid, row, col, value ) {
  if ( col.name === 'status' ) {
    if(value===0)
        value='FALSE';
  }
  return value;
}
```